# Why pushing double on the stack with two 32s bits pushes can be a lot slower than pushing it using float instructions (fldl & fstpl)?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, double, 32-bit, x87

Here is a small piece of assembly code (I use the syntax of the gnu assembler).

```
.extern cos
.section .data
pi: .double 3.14
.section .text
.global slowcos
.global fastcos

fastcos:
  fldl pi         
  subl $8, %esp   # makes some space for a double on the stack
  fstpl 0(%esp)   # copy pi on top of the stack
  call cos
  addl $8, %esp
  ret

slowcos:
  pushl pi+4      # push the last 4 bytes of pi on top of the stack
  pushl pi        # push the first 4 bytes of pi on top of the stack
  call cos
  addl $8, %esp
  retx
```

One can invoke these symbol easily from C with the following prototypes:

```
extern double fastcos ();
extern double slowcos ();
```

They both return the value of "cos(3.14)" but slowcos is two times slower than fastcos on intel 32-bits architecture. My question is the following :

What could explain such a big difference in performance ?

On linux, you can test this by copying this code in a file call cos.asm and by invoking:

```
as --32 cos.asm -o cos.o 
gcc -m32 -O0 cos.o test.c -lm -o test
```

(you can drop --32/-m32 (should ?), if you are not on a 64bits system)
where test.c is the following C source file :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 40000000

extern double fastcos ();
extern double slowcos ();

int main() {
  int k;
  double r; 
  clock_t t;

  t = clock();
  for (k = 0; k < N;k ++) 
    r = fastcos();
  printf ("%gs\n",(double) (clock() - t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  printf("fastcos = %g\n", r);

  t = clock();
  for (k = 0; k < N;k ++)
    r = slowcos();
  printf ("%gs\n",(double) (clock() - t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  printf("slowcos = %g\n", r);

  return 0;
}
```

On my computer it ouputs :

```
1.55687s
fastcos = -0.999999
2.29821s
slowcos = -0.999999
```

One more remark. If you add the line ".global id" in the headers, replace the lines "call cos" in both fastcos and slowcos by "call id" and add the following "double id (double x) { return x; }" in the C file. Then, you obtain:

```
0.360433s
fastpi = 3.14
0.370393s
slowpi = 3.14
```

This code should spend about the same time outside the inner call to the function cos (or id). So this should indicate that the difference happens during the execution of the cosinus function. But I don't understand what could justify such a difference. There is no difference in the alignment of %esp.

Finally, I would like to say that I observed these differences in real-life "numerical" code where the bottleneck is often the computation of "elementary math functions" (like cos or exp). Also, both version are produced by a compiler of high-level programming language. My main concern is to understand what is happening there.

Comment: Load-store forwarding.

Comment: Hmm, pretty sure my compiler will hoist the cos() call out of the loop and then eliminate the loop completely.  So you are probably not running the optimized build.  How do you know it isn't the for() loop that caused the slowdown?  The branch target won't be aligned for example.  Try swapping the calls to slow/fastcos().

Comment: @HansPassant: The compiler doesn't parse assembly, all it has to go on is the function prototype. Without `__attribute__((const))` or something like that, the compiler can't know every call to `fastcos()` does the same. You may be onto something with function alignment though.

Comment: 40 million iterations and only 0.7 seconds slower on a 32 bit machine? Is this worth wasting your brain cells on?

Comment: @e4c5 The performance of such special functions really does matter in real codes.

Comment: @jeff if it really matters why not use the tested and proven built in functions then? Also what really matters is whether a function scales not whether a function runs 1 microsecond faster than another.

Comment: @e4c5 if one can specialize the feature coverage, it's possible to beat the standards. Standard cos has to check for range, take mods, etc. It is worthwhile to understand the right way to implement these functions quickly by hand.

Comment: @HansPassant: I tried to swap the calls and the timing are the same.

Comment: @EOF: Could you be more explicit about the "load-store forwarding". As I said in my edit, It seems that the time spent is inside the call to cos. Do you still think that this could the explanation ?

Comment: @e4c5 it is 30% loss in performance. More over, in real life I am doing more 40 millions iterations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a modern x86 writes to memory, and the same memory is read again shortly afterwards, it *cheats* to avoid doing a full round-trip to memory/cache:

> Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual
>
> 2.3.4.4 Store Forwarding
>
> If a load follows a store and reloads the data that the store writes
>   to memory, the Intel Core microarchitecture can forward the data
>   directly from the store to the load. This process, called store to
>   load forwarding, saves cycles by enabling the load to obtain the data
>   directly from the store operation instead of through memory.

The text goes on about alignment requirements, but the important thing is this:

> The store must be equal or greater in size than the size of data being loaded.

In the slow function, you store the eight-byte double in two chunks of four bytes. Presumably, the `cos()`-function loads it in a single chunk, so the load has to wait until the store is committed to cache.

On the other hand, in the fast function, you store a single eight-byte chunk, which stays in the cpu's internal buffers, from where the load in `cos()` can be satisfied immediately.